# Why am I getting a "Cannot revert to safe mode" error whenever I try to run a game?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm using internal VGA these days and I've got a problem:

I can't run any games.

I always get this errors:

```
--------- [Loading Renderer] ---------
Initializing OpenGL display
...setting fullscreen mode 3: 1024 768
Using XFree86-VidModeExtension Version 2.2
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Depth visual, Stencil Buffered
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Depth visual
ref_gl::R_SetMode() - invalid mode
Initializing OpenGL display
...setting mode 3: 1024 768
Using XFree86-VidModeExtension Version 2.2
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Depth visual, Stencil Buffered
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Error couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered, Depth visual
ref_gl::R_SetMode() - could not revert to safe mode
ref_gl::R_Init() - could not R_SetMode()
```

My motherboard is K8S-MX and I'm using linux 10.04
Do you know how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is the Vendor of your graphics card? It looks like you might not be using the right (or optimized) driver for it.

You can install "mesa-utils" and run "glxinfo" to get more details about the GLX extension on your machine, but since you seem to be using Ubuntu I'd suggest using the "Additional Drivers" thingy that you can find under "System->Administration->Additional Drivers"  to try to let Ubuntu figure out whether you do for example need a binary driver for your card.

Comment: I forgot to uninstall my old drivers. Thank You!